# How to use if statements inside a while loop

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I'm very novice at programming and haven't had any luck in finding a tutorial useful for what I want to do.

I am creating a form that will have 2 drop down selections and then one input box which will produce a price depending on the 2 selections.

For the first drop down it will be a type of event. The second will be a selection of adult, child, or student (each selection has its own set ID). Then I want to produce prices dynamically that will appear in a text box based on the user's selections so something sort of like the following (I'm still figuring out JavaScript so bear with me this will be a poor example):

```
while eventid == 2
{
    if registration == adult;

        price == 45;

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems you need to get in the basics first. Check out [Codeacademy's JavaScript course](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript).

Comment: Yea I can't make heads or tails of this.

Comment: The key: `onchange event` and `change element's content`, try now !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you want a loop, I think the logic that you are looking for is just the if statement, as in "if the registration is an adult, and the event id is 2, then set the price equal to 45" so:

```
if(eventid == 2){
    if(registration == 'adult')
        price = 45;
    if(registration == 'child')
        price = 35;
}
```

Depending on what you want to do, there could be any number of combinations of logical structures you might employ.  A switch statement comes to mind if you have a lot of event ids.

Comment: Cheers, this makes more sense to me now. I have 3 events so if I make 3 separate if statements like in the example above will it be okay to put put them all in one method to call in to the form?

Comment: You got it.  You should look up 'if', 'else', 'for', 'switch', 'while'...these are terms you are going to need to be familiar with if you want to code in javascript.

Comment: Cheers guys, much appreciative of the quick responses. I'll start on tutorials to grasp everything better but this has been a big help for what I wanted to do today, cheers.

Comment: Remember to accept an answer...sort of how this site works. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments that you need to nail down basics - about what you are trying to do and JavaScript itself.

Having said this and based on what you have described, however, I do not think that you need a loop at all.  The event type does not sound like a temporal condition for a repeated series of actions until it changes - the classic criteria for a loop.

It sounds like what you need is more like this:

```
if (eventid == 2) {
    if (registration == 'adult') {
        price = 45;
    } else if (registration == 'child') {
        price = 15; // or whatever
    }// else if... // more registration conditions
} else if (eventid == 3) { // or whatever
    if (registration == 'adult') {
        price = 55; // or whatever
    } else if (registration == 'child') {
        price = 20; // or whatever
    }// else if... // more registration conditions
}// else if... // more eventid conditions
```

Comment: Cheers, this makes more sense to me now. I have 3 events so if I make 3 separate if statements like in the example above will it be okay to put put them all in one method to call in to the form?

Comment: @Nathan:  Exactly - in the event handler(s) for change(s) in the dropdown selection(s) - there being a few ways you could skin that cat but that being the general idea.  Ryan Lynch and I landed in pretty much the same place - the key being that you don't seem to need a loop, rather nested conditionals (whether they be structured as a `switch` with `if`/`else if`(/`else`) nested in each `case` or `if`/`else if`(/`else`) with `if`/`else if`(/`else`) nested in each consequent).